# Comparação entre 2 números iguais retornando 'false'?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php var_dump($fullprice) ?>
<?php var_dump($cart->getData('subtotal')) ?>
<?php var_dump($fullprice == $cart->getData('subtotal')) ?>
```

- `$fullprice` retorna a soma de todos os produtos e quantidades no carrinho.
- `$cart->getData('subtotal')` retorna o subtotal no carrinho.

O resultado:

```
float(319.2) 
float(319.2) 
bool(false)
```

Porque disto? Os 2 valores são iguais, pelo menos foram printados iguais, mas o dump retorna `false`?

**edit:** O código todo aqui

```
<?php /*----------  ##HACK##  ----------*/?>
<?php $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); ?>
<?php $fullprice = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
    <?php $fullprice += ($item->getProduct()->getPrice() * $item->getQty()); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php var_dump($fullprice) ?>
<br>
<?php var_dump($cart->getData('subtotal')) ?>
<br>
<?php var_dump($fullprice == $cart->getData('subtotal')) ?>

<?php if ($fullprice - $cart->getData('subtotal') > 0): ?>
    <p style="color: #319e49; font-size: 16px;">
        <?php echo "Você economizou R$", number_format($fullprice - $cart->getData('subtotal'), 2, ',', ''), "</br>" ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /*----------  ##/HACK##  ----------*/?>
```

Comment: Você consegue criar um exemplo com esse resultado incorreto? parece ter outra coisa interferindo no código.

Comment: `$fullprice` é um array? pela descrição que vc deu na pergunta parece que essa variável 'faz' duas coisas.

Comment: Coloquei o código completo, da uma olhada

Comment: Se vc fiz isso `echo $cart->getData('subtotal') .'<br>'; echo $cart->getData('subtotal');` o mesmo valor é exibido?

Comment: Sinto cheiro de casas decimais não exibidas com valores diferente. Você enxerga 319.2, mas o computador deve enxergar qualquer coisa como 319.2000000000000009 vs. 319.2000000000000000001230123. Arredonde para duas casas decimais (ou quantas forem necessárias pro que você quer) quando for comparar tipos não inteiros.

Comment: @rray retornou: `319.2
319.2
float(319.2) 
float(319.2) 
bool(false)`, sendo os 2 primeiros resultados referentes ao código que vc recomendou

Comment: Usa um [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) ajustado para exibir umas 50 casas que você vai ver porque. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque o valor de `$fullprice` ou de `$cart->getData('subtotal')` é na verdade um número real extremamente próximo a `319.2`, algo como `319.1999999999999`. Você pode reproduzir esse caso com o seguinte teste:

```
<?php

$x = 319.199999999999;
$y = 319.2;
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
var_dump($x == $y);

bash-4.2$ php test.php 
double(319.2)
double(319.2)
bool(false)
```

Números de ponto flutuante são aproximações com precisão limitada em computadores porque estes utilizam o sistema binário, o qual limita a  precisão de representação de números reais, assim números com grande quantidade de casas decimais acabam sendo arredondados. Neste caso aí o valor de `$x` é impresso como `3.2` porque o mecanismo de exibição de PHP arredonda números com uma quantidade de casas decimais menor que o mecanismo de comparação, assim enquanto que um `echo|var_dump` vai arredondar algo como `319.1999999999999` a comparação (`==`) só vai fazer o mesmo para `319.1999999999999999` (tem três noves a mais).

Obs: Uma boa referência introdutória sobre o funcionamento de pontos flutuantes é a própria [documentação do php sobre o assunto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php).

Answer (score 2):

Isso se trata de precisão no PHP o mesmo ocorre em várias outras linguagens de programação. o que se pode fazer para contornar o problema é usar o valor absoluto da diferença dos dois valores e comparar com a constante de EPSILON que corresponde a 0.00001, caso a diferença seja inferior a contante então os valores poderão ser considerados iguais

sendo assim vamos a comparação usando como inspiração o código do nosso caro amigo.

```
    <?php
    // abaixo valores hipotéticos obtidos no script
    // $fullprice tem o valor de: 319.2
    // $cart->getData('subtotal') retornará 319.2

    /* 
     aqui está a comparação que consegue determinar a 
igualdade a partir do valor absoluto da diferença dos
valores com ponto flutuante considerando que o 
resultado dessa diferença seja inferior 
a constante de EPSILON (0.00001)
    */
    if(abs($fullprice - $cart->getData('subtotal')) < 0.00001){
        echo "IGUAIS!";
    }
    else{
        echo "DIFERENTES!";
    }
```